# Rollback the content of a git branch from another branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, diff

I have two git branchs (A and B) out of master. I did some dev on branch B then I merged these dev into A then I decided to delete dev of B branch from A.
How can I achieve this knowing that A branch is changing by other developers :
With a diagram :

```
*--*--*--* <- master
\
 a--b--c <- A
  \
   a'--b'--c' <- B
```

Step1: I Merge B into A

```
*--*--*--* <- master
\
 a--b--c
  \     \
   \     a'--b'--c' <- A
    \
     a'--b'--c' <- B
```

Step 2 : Other developers continue merging their branch into A (commit d, e, f)

```
*--*--*--* <- master
\
 a--b--c
  \     \
   \     a'--b'--c'--d--e--f <- A
    \
     a'--b'--c' <- B
```

Step 3 : I add more commits on branch B (d') then I merge B into A

```
*--*--*--* <- master
\
 a--b--c
  \     \
   \     a'--b'--c'--d--e--f--d' <- A
    \
     a'--b'--c'--d' <- B
```

Now I need to delete all commits of the branch B (a'--b'--c'--d') from the branch A.
How can I achieve this please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with interactive rebase. Assuming for the following example commands that the parent of commit *a* is tagged `parent_of_a`.

Running

```bash
git switch A
git rebase --interactive parent_of_a
```

will give you a list of commits that you can then edit in various ways, of most interest here is the ability to drop certain commits:

```
pick 3bc4d2f a
pick f4a3776 b
pick 7919b36 c
drop c934273 a'
drop a637968 b'
drop 747aea5 c'
pick 46b079b d
pick 26fe1c4 e
pick a981629 f
drop 4e97e2a d'
```

In the text above I changed the initial `pick` to `drop` (you can alternatively just delete the line instead of the explicit `drop` command).
When exiting the editor git will apply it and change the branch correspondingly.

---

Notice that even though there were two merges between `A` and `B`, the default for interactive rebase is to flatten the history and just present a linear line of commits. In this particular case this is not in conflict with what you want. But some times you want to keep existing merge commits (for instance maybe you just want to delete one of the commits on one of the branches that were merged but still keep all the other commits that were merged as a merged branch), and then you need to give an additional `--rebase-merges` argument<sup>1</sup>.

```bash
git rebase --interactive --rebase-merges parent_of_a
```

That will give a slightly different todo list:

```
label onto

# Branch B
reset onto
pick 3bc4d2f a
label branch-point
pick c934273 a'
pick a637968 b'
pick 747aea5 c'
label B

# Branch B-2
reset B # c'
pick 4e97e2a d'
label B-2

reset branch-point # a
pick f4a3776 b
pick 7919b36 c
merge -C 8cd6974 B # Merge branch 'B' into A
pick 46b079b d
pick 26fe1c4 e
pick a981629 f
merge -C 1e77d80 B-2 # Merge branch 'B' into A
```

So there the merge commits are listed explicitly and this flexibility allows you for instance to reorder commits within a branch without changing that the branch is merged. For this example changing to

```
label onto

# Branch B
reset onto
pick 3bc4d2f a
label branch-point
drop c934273 a'
drop a637968 b'
drop 747aea5 c'
label B

# Branch B-2
reset B # c'
drop 4e97e2a d'
label B-2

reset branch-point # a
pick f4a3776 b
pick 7919b36 c
drop 8cd6974 B # Merge branch 'B' into A
pick 46b079b d
pick 26fe1c4 e
pick a981629 f
drop 1e77d80 B-2 # Merge branch 'B' into A
```

gives the same result as the first interactive rebase.

---

If you get conflicts during the rebase, [use KDiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3) (or another full featured 3-way merge capable program). I cannot stress enough how useless the default embedded conflict text markers with only two versions is. After having started using 3-way merge programs you never want to go back.

---

<sup>1</sup> I want to have this as the default, so my `ri` alias is `rebase -i --rebase-merges`.

Comment: thank you for your help. If the commits of B branch was merged to A by 2 merge commits. Can I do 2 revert commits (the merge commits) on branch A to rollback those commits ?